# Yii2 SaaS Authentication

Tags: database, authentication, yii2, saas

I'm Developing SaaS application using Yii2 with separate DB architecture. I have a problem in login to system by using tenant database.

I need to get tenant database details from common db and establish tenant db connection after entering company id, username and password in login form.

This is my index.php file.

```
    <?php
       defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
       defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
       require(__DIR__ . '/_protected/vendor/autoload.php');
       require(__DIR__ . '/_protected/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
       $config = require(__DIR__ . '/_protected/config/web.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config));
if (Yii::$app->session->get('company')) :

    $appConnection = \app\models\Userdbconnections::find()->where(['company_id' => Yii::$app->session->get('company')])->one();
    \Yii::$app->dbDynamic->dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$appConnection->dns";

    \Yii::$app->dbDynamic->username = $appConnection->user;

    \Yii::$app->dbDynamic->password = $appConnection->password;

    \Yii::$app->dbDynamic->charset = 'utf8';    
endif;
Yii::$app->run(); // this will run the application    
?>
```

From login function after post logging data, auth controller is like this

```
if ( Yii::$app->request->post() ){
   $connection = \app\models\Userdbconnections::find()->where(['company_id'=>Yii::$app->request->post('LoginForm')['company']])->one();
                $_SESSION["dsn"] = $connection->dns;
                $_SESSION["user"] = $connection->user;
                $_SESSION["pass"] = $connection->password;
                $_SESSION["company_id"] = $connection->company_id;

               // Yii::$app->db()->close();

                Yii::$app->set('db', [
       'class' => '\yii\db\Connection',
       'dsn' => "mysql:host=localhost;dbname={$connection->dns}",
       'username' => $connection->user,
       'password' =>  $connection->password,
   ]);

                  $model_db = new LoginForm();
                  $model_db->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
                  $model_db->login();


                  $_SESSION["login_user"] = $model_db->username;
}
```

User Management Module called in web.php under component part as following

```
'user' => [
        'class' => 'webvimark\modules\UserManagement\components\UserConfig',

        // Comment this if you don't want to record user logins
        'on afterLogin' => function($event) {

\webvimark\modules\UserManagement\models\UserVisitLog::newVisitor($event->identity->id);
        },
            'enableSession' =>true,
],
```

Each model file consist with following code

```
public static function getDb()

    {

        return Yii::$app->get('dbDynamic');

    }
```

So now i'm able to log from tenant db. But after checking i noticed User Management part, creation, role creation all these linked to common db when ever i logged in to tenant db. Is there anything I misses in here?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is having two connections. One connection for common details coming from common database (user details, tenant db he belongs to, et al). This connection is static, so must be defined in the config (or just rename what comes with Yii Basic app to something like `commonDb` or use it with just `db` name.

Another one will be connected to the specific user tenant database. This will be dynamic and details must change. There are many ways to do it. One is to defined it before app runs. [See this forum post for details](https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/change-db-connection-dynamically/76412/4). Another would be setting it up before request using Yii Container and call it inside your models et al. There might be other ways too.

So the process goes like this

1. User logs in. Connection used is the common connection (let it be defined as Yii::$app->db).
2. Using details from (1) create the dynamic connection.
3. Use the connections where needed (in models, Active data providers or Query builders)

Here is untested example

```
//common database with user login
----------------------------------
| id   | name   | tenant_database |
----------------------------------
|  1    | Stef  | company_a       |
----------------------------------
```

Note here that `Yii::$app->user->identity` will hold model class that wraps this table

```php
//config/web.php
return [
    'components' =>[
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=common_db',
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ]

        'userDb' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=${database}',
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ]
    ]
    //set it up before request
    'on beforeRequest' => function ($event) {
        if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
        {
            // redirect user to Login page
        }
        else
        {
            $currentDSN = Yii::$app->userDb->dsn;
            $tenantDB = Yii::$app->user->identity->tenant_database;
            Yii::$app->userDb->dsn = str_replace('${database}', $tenantDB, $currentDSN);
        }
    },
]
```

Then in model class override  `getDb` as follows

```php
class Data extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function getDb()
    {
        return Yii::$app->userDb;
    }
}
```

Then user it as in:

```php
$data = Data::find()->all();
$data = Yii::$app->userDb->createCommand('SELECT * FROM data')->queryAll();
```

**UPDATE**

Since OP wants the data to be in tenant db, the only way is having each tenant to have special Tenant Code, and on login page you will provide inputs for *Tenant Code*, *Username* and *Password*. Then
1. Query the common table for the database name associated with that code
2. Change Connection details as shown above
3. Login with `TenantLogin` class that uses tenant connection as shown above with `Data` class.

The new common table

```
----------------------------
| code   | tenant_database |
----------------------------
| 12333  | company_a       |
----------------------------
```

Comment: Hi, Here i want to change db connection before login, because tenant user details are in tenant database

Comment: That is wrong design. All users must authenticate against same common database and upon success should retrieve the database. If you insist on your design, check the updates

Comment: If tenants create their users they are in their database. bcoz while creating users they connected to their db

Comment: Hi, I'm able to change db before login. but User identity details are set from previous connection. How can i fix that?

Comment: Can you explain how did you do it? did you follow any of advice or you went with your own? It's hard to help when I don't know which route you went

Comment: `If tenants create their users they are in their database. bcoz while creating users they connected to their db`

That is already solved in my first design. You will save Newly created user with his tenant db (of the current logged in user who is creating new user)

Comment: I thought problem in wrong way. I'm using Yii2 improved version for development. Webvimark user management module for user management. so in this multi tenanting application we keep separate database architecture. I followed several ways. 

https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/change-db-connection-dynamically/76412

this article help me to change db connection after login. but finally i found user management module doesn't get new database connection. how i Solve that case?

Comment: can you update your post with how you change the database and link (minimal) code on how you use the connection on module?

Comment: I have Edited My problem above

Comment: your code is so convoluted and difficult to follow, sorry. You are changing a lot of connection configuration in multiple places. And you have something changing in AfterLogin event and I don't know what it is. I would suggest you pick a clean way that I painfully explained above. I'm not of that help beyond that, sorry!